# Sketch help of geometry problem

Tags: geometry

i need a sketch for this problem  please

A quadrilateral is inscribed in a circle. If an angle is 
inscribed into each of the four segments outside the quadrilateral, the sum of these four angles, expressed in degrees, is:

$\textbf{(A)}\ 1080\qquad  \textbf{(B)}\ 900\qquad  \textbf{(C)}\ 720\qquad  \textbf{(D)}\ 540\qquad  \textbf{(E)}\ 360$

Comment: This sentence "an angle is inscribed into each of the four segments outside the quadrilateral" makes no sense to me, unless you mean the *circular* segments

Comment: @Raffaele   problem  $15$
  http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=1958_AHSME_Problems

Comment: Yes, I realized, now. Students have sometimes difficulties in seeing concave angles. Hope my drawing helps...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the four angles inscribed in the circular segment is half the angle with vertex in the centre of the circle. Each of the $\alpha$ is concave and is $360°$ less the convex part. Adding the $4$ we get $1440°-360°=1080°$ so the sum of the $\beta$ is half that is $540°$

Hope this is useful

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

What you need to compute is $\alpha+\beta+\gamma+\delta=?$